# How can I fill a konva rect with fillPatternImage in React or create an infinite grid with the same svg image in React

Tags: reactjs, image, konvajs, react-konva, konva

I've already created the masonry grid with konva and React here is the example of how far I have come:
https://codesandbox.io/s/masonry-grid-image-konva-react-cp73d

Docs about Konva Image in React https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Images.html

I need to create an infinite grid with the same card [Like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBxQ1.png) but I'm not being able to fill the rect with background image or fill pattern. I'm not being sure about how to create the img object to fill the rect or how to repeat the same image in an infinite grid [with this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nF5K.png)... The svg it's in the codesandbox and this is my current code:

Any help with this will be appreciated

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Stage, Layer, Image, Rect } from "react-konva";
import useImage from "use-image";

const CardImage = () => {
  const [image] = useImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nF5K.png");
  return <Image image={image} />;
};

const WIDTH = 318;
const HEIGHT = 452;

const App = () => {
  const [stagePos, setStagePos] = React.useState({ x: 200, y: 200 });
  const startX = Math.floor((-stagePos.x - window.innerWidth) / WIDTH) * WIDTH;
  const endX = Math.floor((-stagePos.x + window.innerWidth * 2) / WIDTH) * WIDTH;
  const startY = Math.floor((-stagePos.y - window.innerHeight) / HEIGHT) * HEIGHT;
  const endY = Math.floor((-stagePos.y + window.innerHeight * 2) / HEIGHT) * HEIGHT;

  const gridComponents = [];

  for (var x = startX; x < endX; x += WIDTH) {
    for (var y = startY; y < endY; y += HEIGHT) {

      gridComponents.push(
        <>
          <Rect
            x={3.8 * x}
            y={1.2 * y}
            width={WIDTH}
            height={HEIGHT}
            stroke
            shadowBlur={20}
            cornerRadius={10}
          />
          <Rect
            x={3.8 * x + 405}
            y={1.2 * y + 200}
            width={WIDTH}
            height={HEIGHT}
            stroke
            shadowBlur={20}
            cornerRadius={10}
          />
          <Rect
            x={3.8 * x + 810}
            y={1.2 * y + 400}
            width={WIDTH}
            height={HEIGHT}
            stroke
            shadowBlur={20}
            cornerRadius={10}
          />
          <CardImage />
        </>
      );
    }
  }

  return (
    <Stage
      x={stagePos.x}
      y={stagePos.y}
      width={window.innerWidth}
      height={window.innerHeight}
      draggable
      onDragEnd={(e) => {
        setStagePos(e.currentTarget.position());
      }}
    >
      <Layer>{gridComponents}</Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to fill the rectangle with the image you can just use `fillPatternImage` property.

```js
<Rect
  width={WIDTH}
  height={HEIGHT}
  shadowBlur={20}
  cornerRadius={10}
  fillPatternImage={image}
/>
```

To download image you can use a similar way as for `Konva.Image` and `use-image` hook https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Images.html

```js
const [image] = useImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nF5K.png");
```

You updated demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/masonry-grid-image-konva-react-forked-s2wku?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Well it's was easier than I thought. Thanks a lot! The thing is that it's working really slow compared to codesandbox. Is there any way to fill it with an svg?

Comment: You can use svg too as image source. The demo is slow, because it has too many shapes, you just need to have shapes, that are inside a viewport (or very close to it).

Comment: Yeah thanks! I already use the svg file as source. I'm not very experienced in konva as you can notice. Do you have an idea on how to manage each card / rect individually to change on click event? and is there any docs on how to show the cards close to the viewport? Thank for your help I really appreciate it!